# How to install AdminLTE 3 with Bootstrap 4 for my Yii2 Advanced Project?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new with yii2. How can I install AdminLTE 3 with Bootstrap 4 in my Yii2 Advanced Project? Is it possible to illustrate all the steps?

Comment: did you googled that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A simple googling result:**

There is a package available on Github. You can add [Yii 2 AdminLTE 3](https://github.com/kmergen/yii2-adminlte3) package to your Yii2 advanced project:

by either runing

```
composer require "kmergen/yii2-adminlte3: "*"
```

or adding

```
"kmergen/yii2-adminlte": "*",
```

to the require section of your composer.json file.

Also it has an example and all the steps to do on [this page](https://github.com/kmergen/yii2-adminlte3/tree/master/examples/themes/adminlte). you can follow up the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require hail812/yii2-adminlte3
```

https://packagist.org/packages/hail812/yii2-adminlte3

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer